# Resource cannot be found on RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I need redirect user depend of the result returned from Repository, nothing special. I do not have idea why this error happens.
Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Form(PaymentViewModel pvm)
  {
     string actionName = null;
     actionName = pr.MakePayment(pvm) == true ? "Success" : "Failed"; 
     return RedirectToAction(actionName, "Payment");
  }
```

Comment: Do you have public action "Success" and "Failed" defined in controller Payment?

Comment: Do you have the action methods written with the following names under controller "Payment"
1. Success
2.Failed

Comment: That's it! I forgot to write action methods!

Comment: @MohamedAlikhan, please add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the action methods with the following names under controller "Payment" 
 1. Success 
 2. Failed
Thats it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

> Resource cannot be found on RedirectToAction

Another scenario where this error will show up is when a page refresh is required while the ActionMethod being directed to, for some wicked reason, is marked with an HttpPost attribute.

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeActionMethod()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestRedirection()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SomeActionMethod", "Some");
    }
}
```

Story short, remove the HttpPost from the method that returns the View.